# Running Python3 / Spyder3 under openSUSE

Tags: python, anaconda, opensuse, spyder

I tried a long time to get Spyder working with python 3.4 support. I have Python 3.4 and 2.7 installed on my openSuse/gnome Denktop. I also installed anaconda and anaconda3 in my home folder. They created the following lines in the .bashrc :

```
# added by Anaconda3 2.3.0 installer
# export PATH="/home/sbrems/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"


# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/sbrems/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Like this I can now type "spyder" in the shell and Spyder will open with python2.7 support. If I change the "#" from Anaconda3 to Anaconda and type spyder then, I will get the following errormessage:

```
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator.py", line 156
    exec code in evaldict
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'exec'
```

This is clear, as he looks in the python2.7 instead of python 3.4 folder, and for python3 you need brackets around many commands such as print(). But how do I get it to look in the python3.4 directory?
I also tried to install spyder3 via

```
sudo zypper install spyder3
```

But running spyder3 then ends in the same error as above, as it also looks in the wrong directory...

I really have no idea how to get spyder running python3, because manually changing the compiler in spyder also gives the warning, that syntax highlighting and other spyder features won't work correctly, as it still assumes python2 coding...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` environment variables set?

Comment: Hey asmeurer,
where should I set these variables? So I guess I didn't set them..I tried adding
PYTHONHOME ="/usr/lib/python3.4/" 
in the .bashrc which didn't change anything...

Comment: Hey asmeurer,
thanks, after googling a bit for pythonhome and pythonpath it works now :) I just had to add export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.4 to the .bashrc  :) . When I want to use python2.7 I just comment this line together with the path to anaconda3 and uncomment the path to anaconda. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Neither of these variables should be set. Setting them tends to cause problems like this.

Comment: They weren't set before. Neither in the .bashrc nor in the .profile in my home folder. And without them it didn't work for whatever reason. So if someone has a suggestion what to do else, I would prefer not to set them, before more weird problems arise.

Comment: If you just run `python` in the terminal and `import decorator` does it work?